# OpenCV - RTSP streaming FFMPEG error

Tags: java, opencv3.0

I'm building a face recognition software in java using OpenCV 3.2.0 version and I'm trying to get the RTSP stream of a HIKVISION DS-2CD2420F-IW IP camera. The main video stream is encoded in H.264 format. The video stream is served over rtsp protocol. When I'm trying to capture the video stream in my java application, I'm getting below error:

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779) 

while (runnable){
    if (webSource.grab()) {
       try {
            webSource.retrieve(frame);
            Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
            faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
            for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
               // System.out.println("ttt");
                Imgproc.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),                                    new Scalar(0, 255,0));
                Imgproc.putText(frame, "Detecting", new Point(rect.x, rect.y), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, new Scalar(0, 0, 255));
             }
            Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
            if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()-150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null)) {
            if (runnable == false) {
                System.out.println("Paused ..... ");
                this.wait();
            }
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("Error");
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Lol i worked with Hikvision and Opencv too. OpenCV need a special image format. You should try to use OpenCV with a local image first, then use ffmpeg outside the openCV library.

Comment: And share your code.

Comment: @pirs, its working fine now. The port number was the culprit.

Comment: @pirs, is there a simple way to detect motion using OpenCV?

Comment: @pirs, I also observed that when I stream the video with H.264 encoding enabled, video is hanging and my application is exiting unexpectedly. I have  set StreamType to MainStream. I also tested with resolutions of 1920x1080P, 1280x960, 1280x720P with a frame rate of 5 fps, but its still hanging and exiting after 5 secs.

Comment: OpenCV isnt simple and need good level of coding to be mastered, about ffmpeg capture, in the command, you should try firstly something like `ffmpeg -loglevel 99 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:pass@ip:port/Channel/1/Streaming/ -c:v libx264 -preset medium -r 20 output.ts` to capture video and `ffmpeg -loglevel 99 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:pass@ip:port/Channel/1/Streaming/ -f image2 -vf fps=5 -q:v 2 output-%d.jpeg` to test. I let you read the doc to understand what is it : https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Comment: And know that Hikvision is used by the chinese governement as a spy cam with a worm inside, all embassies and industried in the world banned this brand.